# Existe alguma diferença entre a função is_file e file_exists?

Tags: php

Por acaso, existe alguma diferença entre a função `is_file` e `file_exists`?

```
var_dump(file_exists('public/index.php'); // bool(true)

var_dump(is_file('public/index.php')); // bool(true);
```

Teóricamente, os dois teriam o mesmo sentido, já que `is file` é equivalente à "é arquivo?" e `file_exists` é equivante a "arquivo existe?"

Se é um arquivo que existe, é um arquivo. E se é um arquivo, ele existe.

Então, qual é a diferença entre essas funções?

Comment: `is_file` acho que é pra ver se não é diretório... só ver o manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

Comment: Pra ver se não é diretório eu só uso `!is_dir($file)`

Comment: Puts, muitas respostas iguais! efeito cascata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim existem algumas diferenças:

[file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) verifica se existe o diretório ou o arquivo, passado como argumento.

[is_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) A definição do manual é

> Tells whether the given file is a **regular** file.
>
> Informa se o arquivo/string passado como argumento é um arquivo **regular**

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6858520/1342547) do SOen, alguns exemplos de  arquivos não regulares são:

- devices
- pipes
- sockets

Basicamente o que a função faz é checar se a string(`$filename`) informada é válida ou seja não contém [caracteres *estranhos*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php#104505) caso positivo verifica se `$filename` representa um arquivo, do contrario retorna `false`.

Fiz alguns testes comparando as duas funções, o resultado é tabela abaixo

Estrutura do projeto

```
Raiz
  foo
    3.txt - Atalho.lnk 
  txt
    1.txt
    abců.txt
    ů.txt
  ů
```

---

```
<?php
   var_dump(is_file('foo')); //pasta
   var_dump(is_file('txt/1.txt')); //arquivo
   var_dump(is_file('C:\\')); //device
   var_dump(is_file('txt/abců.txt')); //arquivo com caracter estranho
   var_dump(is_file('txt/ů.txt')); //arquivo com caracter estranho
   var_dump(is_file('txt/ů')); // pasta com caracter estranho

   var_dump(file_exists('foo')); //pasta
   var_dump(file_exists('txt/1.txt')); //arquivo
   var_dump(file_exists('C:\\')); // device
   var_dump(file_exists('txt/ů.txt')); //arquivo com caracter estranho
   var_dump(file_exists('txt/abců.txt')); //arquivo com caracter estranho
   var_dump(file_exists('ů'); //pasta com caracter estranho
```

Resultado:

```
     X      |Pasta |Arquivo|Device|Pasta ou arquivo com caracter estranho
is_file     |false |true   |false |false
file_exists |true  |true   |true  |false
```

Comment: Puts! Essa eu não sabia! Quando quero saber se um diretório existe, eu uso `is_dir`. PHP confuso!

Comment: vamos combinar: `file_exists` pra saber se um diretório existe, é muito sem noção! Muito incoerente!

Comment: Ta na documentação =\. O PHP não é coerente em nada. Quer dizer so em confusão :D rs

Comment: Acha que fui troll no meu comentário: _Se é um arquivo que existe, é um arquivo. E se é um arquivo, ele existe._?

Comment: É que _file_ também pode ter um significado mais amplo, de um item qualquer do _file system_ que pode ser tanto um arquivo como um diretório. Veja por exemplo na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file): _"Within this definition, it is of paramount importance that the term "file" includes directories."_

Comment: @Piovezan, entendi sua colocação. Faz sentido

Comment: @Piovezan, editei a resposta, rs nunca tinha ouvido esse termo 'arquivo regular'.

Answer (score 5):

O `is_file` retorna `true` apenas se o caminho for de um arquivo(não diretório/symlink). O `file_exists` não faz essa distinção e retorna `true` se "algo" existir no caminho.

**EDIT (só pra complementar)**

Há funções equivalentes ao `is_file` para verificar diretórios e symlinks, estas são `is_link`<sup>1</sup> e `is_dir`<sup>2</sup>.

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: +1 Essa informação dos links simbólicos são importantes.

Answer (score 1):

Documentações dos métodos:

`file_exists()` - Checa se um arquivo ou diretório existe
`is_file()` - Informa se o arquivo é um arquivo comum (não é diretório)

Referências:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-file.php

Answer (score 1):

`is_file` verifica se o arquivo é um arquivo válido/existente. Mas não funciona se verificar apenas diretórios.

```
var_dump(is_file('a_file.txt')) . "\n";
var_dump(is_file('/usr/bin/')) . "\n";
```

retorno:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Em contrapartida, `file_exists` funciona, também, para verificar a existência de diretórios.

**Um ponto a se levantar é:**

O que se espera de uma função que faz/verifica mais de uma coisa? Que ela seja mais lenta em comparação a outras. Seria interessante fazer testes a respeito disso e ver qual se sai melhor no seu contexto.

Referências:

[Manual: is_file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-file.php),
[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php)