# file_exists, só que não: erro no teste com falso TRUE

Tags: php, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos, diretório

Esta não é exatamente uma pergunta direta, mas pode ser interessante já que existe outra discussão aqui sobre file_exists vs is_file.

Eu, como muitos programadores, defino variáveis para me achar no ambiente - estrutura de arquivos, tipo assim:

```
$dirRoot = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/";
```

Quando entra um arquivo, completa-se assim:

```
$dirArquivo = $dirRoot.$arquivo;
```

Mas um erro comum é o $arquivo estar vazio (o mané do usuário não preencheu o campo), nesse caso, se testarmos $dirArquivo com file_exists vai ocorrer um falso TRUE. Vejam um código de teste:

```
$dirRoot = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/";
$arquivo = "index.php";
$dirArquivo = $dirRoot.$arquivo;
$txtResult = "Teste file_exists para ".$arquivo."\n";
$txtResult .= "Diretório ".$dirRoot."\n";
$txtResult .= "Caminho para o arquivo ".$dirArquivo."\n";
$txtResult .= "\nNome errado: ";
$txtResult .= (file_exists("nindex.php"))? "TRUE" : "FALSE" ;
$txtResult .= "\nSem diretório: ";
$txtResult .= (file_exists($arquivo))? "TRUE" : "FALSE" ;
$txtResult .= "\nCom diretório (usual): ";
$txtResult .= (file_exists($dirArquivo))? "TRUE" : "FALSE" ;
$txtResult .= "\nSem arquivo (erro comum): ";
$txtResult .= (file_exists($dirRoot))? "TRUE" : "FALSE" ;
echo($txtResult);
```

Resultado:

```
Teste file_exists para index.php
Diretório /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
Caminho para o arquivo /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php

Nome errado: FALSE
Sem diretório: TRUE
Com diretório (usual): TRUE
Sem arquivo (erro comum): TRUE
```

Vejam que o file_exists retorna TRUE porque é um diretório e existe, e ele testa os dois. Uma alternativa é usar is_file ou combinar assim:

```
if(file_exists($dirRoot.$arquivo) && $arquivo)
```

Em ambos os casos, me parece uma gambiarra. Existe alguma maneira certa de lidar com isso? É aceitável programar assim?

Comment: O mané do usuário não preencheu o campo ou foi o mané do programador que não validou? :P

Comment: Será que sua pergunta na verdade não é: *Quando usar file_exists() ou is_file()* ? Também, por que  você chama o usuário de *mané* por ele não ter preenchido algum campo se o seu sistema permite isso?

Comment: _"É aceitável programar assim?"_ Sem validação? Claro que não é aceitável. Basta **um** programador para evitar falhas que **infinitos** usuários podem cometer. Entendido isso, de qual dos lados é a responsabilidade de validar os dados mesmo? Ou você acredita na desculpa da "falta de treinamento" que muita empresinha de TI alega quando a coisa não funciona?

Comment: Além disso, já foi respondido aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99992/arquivo-existe-php

Comment: Mas o que eu estou fazendo é justamente validar o arquivo, ver se ele existe. O campo pode ser validado via JS mas pode acontecer um outro erro que leve ao $arquivo a vir vazio... além disso eu mesmo coloquei as diferenças entre file_exists e is_file... desculpe se ofendi alguém, minha intenção era apenas debater a prática de programação... na minha experiência, partir o princípio que a variável está correta porque outra etapa já validou é arriscado.

Comment: @user6492 Você não ofendeu nenhum de nós, só os "pobres" dos usuários – ok, nem sempre tão pobres assim :) Sobre validar, você precisa validar no servidor, JS não basta. Precisa ver se o nome do arquivo veio vazio. Se veio, devolve a pessoa para o formulário, e nem processa. Se a pessoa nem indicou o nome do arquivo, faz sentido você verificar se o arquivo [sem nome] já existe? Não faz! Como mostra a pergunta linkada, o `file_exists`, apesar do nome, se comporta como um "path_exists", pois verifica o caminho completo. Se ele aponta para um dir que existe, dá `true`. Não tem como mudar isso.

Comment: [Existe alguma diferença entre a função is_file e file_exists?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85459/91)

Comment: @bfavaretto Você respondeu a pergunta! Eu fiquei pensando e acho que simplifiquei demais a questão e não rendeu a discussão. O problema real ocorreu em um sistema que lê uns metadados e compõe o $arquivo e é composto de várias bibliotecas. Ocorreram erros "em cascata" e ficou difícil descobrir a fonte. O teste então é feito muitas vezes e eu fiquei em dúvida se estava fazendo uma gambiarra muitas vezes. Vou me puxar mais na pergunta da próxima vez!